# Using Joins to get all data from left table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables as shown below.

```
Id Name                            Id   Status
--------                           -------------------
1   A                              1        Approved
2   B                              6        Approved
3   C                              4        Pending
4   D                              1        Approved
5   E                              1        Pending
6   F                              3        Pending
                                   5        Rejected
```

Now this is how I want the output to be:

```
Id  Name  Status
-------------------
1    A    Pending
2    B    
3    C    Pending 
4    D    Pending
5    E
6    F
```

I have tried using left join but I am getting multiple rows.

```
select t1.ID,Name,Status from t1 left join t2 on t1.id=t2.id
```

and if I add where Status=pending i am getting only ids 1 and 3.
    Here are the queries i tried:

```
select distinct t1.id,name,status from t1 left join t2 on t1.id=t2.id  (this gives me duplicate records i.e id 1 is occurs twice with approved and pending)
```

and also

```
select distinct t1.id,name,status from t1 left join t2 on t1.id=t2.id where t2.status='pending'  (gives me only 1,3 and 4)
```

Could any one help me,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why doesn't `Id = 4` have a Pending `Status`?

Comment: What is the primary key of `t2`? Can you actually have duplicate rows as shown with `( 1, Approved)`? If so what should be shown in the result for that if there are multiple `pending` rows for an `id`?

Comment: @Lamak i have corrected it. I missed it intially.

Comment: @MartinSmith i think i have shown in the third table what i am expecting the output to be.

Comment: @Sravan So, an `Id` on table 2 can have the same `Status` more than once?. And if so, you only need to know that once upon a time it had a `pending` status?

Comment: The issue doesn't arise in your example data so that doesn't help. I'm asking is it actually possible there might be multiple pending rows for one `id`? And if so should the result have one row or multiple?

Comment: @MartinSmith Not exactly. there would be only one pending row at anu guven time..

Comment: @Lamak there will be only pending status for a given id any time and multiple number of apprved and rejected status.

Comment: Ah OK that's lucky. No need for me to edit my answer then.

Comment: @MartinSmith Cool. Can you just tell me How would it be like just in case there are multiple pending status and i still want to show it as a single row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To include all rows from `T1` and only those from `T2` with `status = 'pending'` move the condition into the `ON` clause [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/11d54/1)

```
SELECT t1.ID,
       Name,
       Status
FROM   t1
       LEFT JOIN t2
         ON t1.id = t2.id
            AND t2.status = 'pending'
```

To only return one row per `id` in the event of dupes you could do ([Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/11d54/4))

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT id, Status
FROM T2
WHERE Status = 'Approved' 
)
SELECT t1.ID,
       Name,
       Status
FROM   t1
       LEFT JOIN CTE
         ON t1.id = CTE.id
```

Comment: NB: I'm assuming the omission of `Id = 4` in the desired results is an error.

Comment: +1, this should be the right answer, and `Id = 4` is most likely an error. Maybe you can use a `DISTINCT` or a way to make the combination of `Id` and `Status` unique on table `t2`, since the test data shows 2 rows with `Id = 1` and `Status = 'Approved'`; this could also happen with `Status = 'pending'`

Comment: @Lamak - Good point. Will wait for the OP to clarify that one.